# Solutions of certain differential equations in two variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $\phi:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function such that $\phi(a)=\phi(b)=0,$ and let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary points. Suppose we have another fixed smooth path $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

How do I prove that there always exists a smooth $\psi:\mathbb{R} \times [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:
$$\psi(0,t)= f(t), \psi(s,a)=x, \psi(s,b)=y$$ and $$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \psi(0,t)= \phi(t)?$$

I would assume to use some version of Picard-Lindelöf, but I do not see how to apply it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a differential equation. A differential equation would relate the derivative(s) of $\psi(s,t)$ to $s$, $t$, and $\psi(s,t)$ throughout the domain. Your equations are essentially just boundary conditions and initial conditions for $\psi$.

In order to find such a function, you have to stipulate first that $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$; otherwise the conditions are self-contradictory.

With this assumption, there are many such functions, but here's a simple one that you can write down explicitly:
$$
\psi(s,t) = f(t) + s\phi(t).
$$